# How much sheetrock overhang is okay on a ceiling?

Tags: drywall, framing

I am removing a closet wall in an upstairs bedroom. The wall runs parallel to the ceiling joists. The ceiling sheetrock is 1/2". That sheetrock edge was resting on the closet sheetrock which has been removed.

Do I need to install another 2x4 and attach it to that sheetrock or is overhang okay?

Comment: Ceiling sheetrock should be nailed/screwed to ceiling joists, the wall should not be holding it up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are speaking of is the drywall on the wall of the closet (that is now removed) was vertically butting up to the edge of the ceiling drywall. This is a normal and preferred installation method. (To install ceiling first and have the wall boards meet them.)

Your question of how far the ceiling board can hang wild can be a matter of opinion. Since you didn't state differently, one must assume your goal is to add new drywall on the ceiling butting up to the old ceiling piece. To make the joints even and neat it would be advisable to add a 2x4 as deadwood to screw the 2 adjourning edges to.